# How to get rows where a set of columns are equal to a given value in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with many columns (around 1000).
Given a set of columns (around 10), which have 0 or 1 as values, I would like to select all the rows where I have 1s in the aforementioned set of columns.

Toy example. My dataframe is something like this:

```
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
'a',1,1,0,1
'b',0,1,0,0
'c',0,0,1,1
'd',0,1,0,0
'e',1,0,0,1
```

And I would like to get the rows where the columns c2 and c5 are equal to 1:

```
'a',1,1,0,1
'e',1,0,0,1
```

Which would be the most efficient way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This would be more generic for multiple columns `cols`

```
In [1277]: cols = ['c2', 'c5']

In [1278]: df[(df[cols] == 1).all(1)]
Out[1278]:
    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
0  'a'   1   1   0   1
4  'e'   1   0   0   1
```

Or,

```
In [1284]: df[np.logical_and.reduce([df[x]==1 for x in cols])]
Out[1284]:
    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
0  'a'   1   1   0   1
4  'e'   1   0   0   1
```

Or,

```
In [1279]: df.query(' and '.join(['%s==1'%x for x in cols]))
Out[1279]:
    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
0  'a'   1   1   0   1
4  'e'   1   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing something like this:

```
df.loc[df['c2'] == 1 & df['c5'] == 1]
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to make a function, so I'd need a more generic solution.

Comment: Nothing prevent you from making "c2" and "c5" and the targets as variables.
You have everything you need to transform this to a function

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

frame = pd.DataFrame([
['a',1,1,0,1],
['b',0,1,0,0],
['c',0,0,1,1],
['d',0,1,0,0],
['e',1,0,0,1]], columns='c1,c2,c3,c4,c5'.split(','))

print(frame.loc[(frame['c2'] == 1) & (frame['c5'] == 1)])
```